# Azure DevOps agent in Docker: add custom capabilities

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I run Azure DevOps agents in Docker as per guide on DockerHub:

```
docker run -d -e VSTS_ACCOUNT='kagarlickij' \
    -e VSTS_POOL='Self-Hosted-Containers' \
    -e VSTS_TOKEN='a***q' \
    mcr.microsoft.com/azure-pipelines/vsts-agent:ubuntu-16.04-docker-18.06.1-ce
```

I'd like to automatically add custom capabilities to agent, how is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create an agent, add the capability in the command. For example: `docker run -d -e VSTS_ACCOUNT={account} -e VSTS_POOL={pool} -e VSTS_AGENT={agent} -e VSTS_TOKEN={token} -e myvar=test -it mcr.microsoft.com/azure-pipelines/vsts-agent:ubuntu-16.04-docker-18.06.1-ce`. I've tested on my side, I can see `myvar` shows in the capabilities.

Comment: Sorry, the question is not about adding binaries into Docker image with ADOS agent (it's clear) but how to announce functionality in custom capabilities of the agent (I've added picture to make it more clear)

Comment: I see. When you create agent, add the capability in the command. For example: `docker run -d -e VSTS_ACCOUNT={account} -e VSTS_POOL={pool} -e VSTS_AGENT={agent} -e VSTS_TOKEN={token} -e myvar=test -it mcr.microsoft.com/azure-pipelines/vsts-agent:ubuntu-16.04-docker-18.06.1-ce`. I've tested on my side, I can see `myvar` shows in the capabilities.